# Can you get different ships in Elite?

Tags: elite

I am hoping someone reading this played the original Elite. I was thinking about buying the origin NES cartridge to play the game but I want to know if you can buy new ships.

I read the game manual and couldn't easily find reference to buying a new ship, however there was a long list of other ships in the manual all with differing cargo bay sizes and weapons capacity etc

I'd love it if you can buy ships. Otherwise I might get a bit bored just flying the skywinder or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. You can purchase upgrades for CMDR Jameson's Cobra Mk. III, including improved weapons and increased cargo capacity, but you cannot purchase a new ship in Elite.

Comment: Ah that is a shame. I would upvote your answer but since I am brand new here it isn't letting me

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying Keep in mind that the game is free for PC on the Frontier Store, including the necessary emulator to actually run the game on a modern PC

Comment: That is brilliant. I did notice it was free however I am trying to build up a physical Nes collection and I think Elite is a game that deserves to be in that collection :)